# Uploading file on website using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, https

I have this script but return me '405 Method now allow'. Any ideea ? I try with Post/Put but doesn't work.

Script:

```
$uri = "https://site/upload"
$uploadPath = "C:\users\me\Desktop\test.zip"
$user = "User"
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $pwd)
$contentType = "multipart/form-data"
    $body = @{
        "FileName" = Get-Content($uploadPath) -Raw
    }
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Credential $cred -Method POST -ContentType $contentType -Body $body
```

Site:

```
<!-- general form elements -->
                    <form name="uploadlog" role="form" action="https://site/uploadlog" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="asof2TESTNDNwu1u2">

<div class="box-body">

                            <div class="form-group has-feedback ">
                                                                    <label for="zipfile">Chose (ID.zip , ID.cab, ID.log, ID_Device.log)</label>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
                                    <input type="file" id="zipfile" name="zipfile" accept=".zip,.cab,.log">
```

Comment: Try to capture a trace of the HTTP request sent when you upload *manually* through a browser (e.g. use Fiddler to view the HTTP traffic) - assuming this actually works - and then compare that to what the PowerShell code is sending. Then, adjust your PowerShell script until it sends the same request as the manual process does in a browser.

Comment: Hello mclayton , First of all thanks for your response. I try to capture trace of https but I obtain only this:

`documentLifecycle active
frameType outermost_frame
initiator https://example.com
method GET
url https://example.com/upload
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.9,ro;q=0.8
Referer https://example.com/upload
Sec-Fetch-Dest document
Sec-Fetch-Mode navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests 1

+ some request from unpkg. com`

Comment: `POST /uploadlog HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com:443
Accept: <...>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryP2...
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 28 Nov 2022 13:00:10 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Location: https://example.com/upload
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
`